# WebDriver should be returning list but it's returning webelement

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, strip

I have no clue why this is happening. I'm trying to convert what the webdriver returned (a money value of $1.00) to an integer so I can run it through a called function, but I can't split to take away the $ because of this error. Here is my code:

```
    element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".something")[0]
    element2 = element.find_elements_by_tag_name('tag')[19]
    [s.split('$')[0:] for s in element2]
    element3 = int(element2)
    print(elment3.text)
```

I'm getting this reject

```
    TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

Shouldn't this be a list and be iterable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

`WebElement` or `WebDriver` both are **non-iterable.** when you do `find_elements` it returns a list of web element that you can iterate.

Comment: I'm using a find_elements function

Comment: `element.find_elements_by_tag_name('tag')[19]` - this will return a single web element not list

Answer (score 0):

`element.find_elements_by_tag_name('tag')` is probably indeed a list, but you are grabbing the element at index 19 -- so `element2` is just a webelement. I don't know what you are trying to do, but that's why your code isn't working.

Comment: I see, since I'm telling it to just grab one thing it's telling me it's treating as a list and instead just a single webelement. It's a dollar value that I need to manipulate into a function. Do you have any idea how I can make that happen?

Comment: *It's a dollar value that I need to manipulate into a function.* Exactly where is this dollar value in your code? Also I don’t know what it means to “manipulate into a function”….. do you mean pass it in as an argument?

Comment: That's correct, it will be an argument. The dollar value will be returned by the 'tag'.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out!
It was:

```
element3 = element2.text.strip('$')
```